# libssl issue using paramiko and sshtunnel with docker alpine

Tags: python, docker, paramiko, alpine-linux, ssh-tunnel

I have been struggling with some process for while now and I decided to come shout for help.

I have a script that suppose to download some file and drop it inside some sftp server for batch processing.

I am using alpine python container and my Dockerfile looks like below

```
FROM python:3.7.1-alpine3.8

RUN \
echo "**** install build packages ****" && \
apk add --no-cache --virtual=build-dependencies \
g++ \
gcc \
make \
libffi-dev \
openssl-dev \
openssl \
python-dev && \
echo "**** install pip packages ****" && \
pip install --no-cache-dir -U \
pip && \
pip install --no-cache-dir -U \
cryptography \
paramiko \
sshtunnel \
datetime \
boto3 \
requests \
datetime && \
echo "**** clean up ****" && \
apk del --purge \
gcc \
g++\
make \
build-dependencies && \
rm -rf \
/root/.cache \
/var/cache/apk/* \
/tmp/*

COPY settle.py /
CMD [ "python3", "./settle.py" ]
```

I have a file called settle.py which relevant snippet is:

```
print("creating the tunnel")
  with SSHTunnelForwarder(
      (loaded_json["sftp_jumpbox_address"],int(loaded_json["sftp_jumpbox_port"])),
      ssh_username=loaded_json["sftp_jumpbox_user"],
      ssh_pkey=privateJumpboxKey,
      remote_bind_address=(loaded_json["sftp_target_address"],int(loaded_json["sftp_target_port"])),
      local_bind_address=("127.0.0.1",2222)

  ) as tunnel:
    print("making actual ssh paramiko connection")
    client = paramiko.SSHClient()
    client.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    pemkey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(privateTargetKey)
    client.connect(hostname="127.0.0.1",port=2222,username=loaded_json["sftp_target_user"],pkey=pemkey, look_for_keys=False)
    print("Making the sftp connection")
    sftp = client.open_sftp()
    # filename="testing_20181119114841390.txt"
    # print(loaded_json)
    uploadFolder= targetUploadFolder+"/"
    print("destination file "+ filename)
    sftp.chdir(uploadFolder)
    print("dropping the file into the sftp")
    sftp.put(sourceFileToSend,filename)
    print("Closing the sftp connection")
    sftp.close()
    client.close()

    print("Completing the upload")
except Exception as e:
  print("type error: " + str(e))
```

Each time I run it no matter which combination of package, python-dev , cryptograpy I install I still end up with the following error

`creating the tunnel
type error: Error loading shared library libssl.so.1.0.0: No such file or directory (needed by /usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/cryptography/hazmat/bindings/_openssl.abi3.so)`

Meanwhile this python script runs perfectly well on my mac. I am not sure what I am missing . I will be grateful if anyone can shed some lights. Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**
I have sshed into the container and when I did a search , below is what I found

```
/ # find / -iname libssl*
/lib/libssl.so.45
/lib/libssl.so.45.0.1
/usr/lib/libssl.so.45
/usr/lib/libssl.so.45.0.1
```

Right now not sure which one of the library needs an update of needs a symbolic link to libssl. As version available is way recent than the one required by the cryptography libraby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying so many other things with Alpine, I stumble upon this post from [Linux and Unix](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/447658/22197) where it's said to be careful about C/C++ written python libraries. So I switched to a debian based distro and mehn it was ridiculously simple. The Dockerfile below works perfectly.

```
FROM python:3.6-slim-jessie


RUN pip install --no-cache-dir -U \
cffi \
paramiko \
sshtunnel \
datetime \
boto3 \
requests \
datetime && \
echo "**** clean up ****" && \
rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
COPY settle.py /
CMD [ "python", "./settle.py" ]
```